# Group by candidate key and update the records for batching

Tags: oracle

```
create table SCHEDULED_TIMER_EVENTS(

             STATUS varchar(50),
              EVENT_NAME varchar(50),
              CUSOTOMER_ID varchar(50),
              PROD_CODE varchar(50),              
              FILE_WORKITEM_ID varchar(50),
             PROCESSING_BATCH_ID varchar(50)
);



insert into SCHEDULED_TIMER_EVENTS values ('PENDING','ALERT1',1,1,1,1);
insert into SCHEDULED_TIMER_EVENTS values ('PENDING','ALERT1',2,2,2,2);
insert into SCHEDULED_TIMER_EVENTS values ('PENDING','ALERT1',1,1,1,3);
insert into SCHEDULED_TIMER_EVENTS values ('PENDING','ALERT1',1,1,1,4);
insert into SCHEDULED_TIMER_EVENTS values ('PENDING','ALERT1',1,1,1,5);

select * from SCHEDULED_TIMER_EVENTS;
```

how do i create a unique PROCESSING_BATCH_ID for further processing
depending on the candidate key of customer_id, prod_code

Comment: Use a sequence, it will generate globally unique identifier, which of course will also be unique per group

Answer (score 0):

A sequence and simply omitting the column on insert will take care of it

```
SQL> create sequence PROCESSING_BATCH_ID_SEQ;

Sequence created.

SQL>
SQL> create table SCHEDULED_TIMER_EVENTS(
  2               STATUS varchar(50),
  3                EVENT_NAME varchar(50),
  4                CUSOTOMER_ID varchar(50),
  5                PROD_CODE varchar(50),
  6                FILE_WORKITEM_ID varchar(50),
  7               PROCESSING_BATCH_ID varchar(50)
  8  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> alter table SCHEDULED_TIMER_EVENTS
  2  modify PROCESSING_BATCH_ID default PROCESSING_BATCH_ID_SEQ.nextval;

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> insert into SCHEDULED_TIMER_EVENTS ( STATUS,EVENT_NAME,CUSOTOMER_ID,PROD_CODE,FILE_WORKITEM_ID) values ('PENDING','ALERT1',1,1,1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into SCHEDULED_TIMER_EVENTS ( STATUS,EVENT_NAME,CUSOTOMER_ID,PROD_CODE,FILE_WORKITEM_ID) values ('PENDING','ALERT1',2,2,2);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into SCHEDULED_TIMER_EVENTS ( STATUS,EVENT_NAME,CUSOTOMER_ID,PROD_CODE,FILE_WORKITEM_ID) values ('PENDING','ALERT1',1,1,1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into SCHEDULED_TIMER_EVENTS ( STATUS,EVENT_NAME,CUSOTOMER_ID,PROD_CODE,FILE_WORKITEM_ID) values ('PENDING','ALERT1',1,1,1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into SCHEDULED_TIMER_EVENTS ( STATUS,EVENT_NAME,CUSOTOMER_ID,PROD_CODE,FILE_WORKITEM_ID) values ('PENDING','ALERT1',1,1,1);

1 row created.
```